# Co-ordinate Transformation / Effects

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, acceleration

The Lorentz transform relates two frames of reference with Linear velocity w.r.t each other, to each other. If one frame of reference is experiencing zero proper acceleration, but another frame of reference is in Circular Motion, does this have any significant consequences and how can I transform between one frame of reference to the Other?

Comment: The Lorentz transformation relates *inertial* reference frames.  However, accelerated frames can be treated, with care, in special relativity (SR).  I know that uniform circular motion in SR has been treated here.  Have you searched the site for this?

Comment: I did but couldn't find another, a link would be appreciated

Comment: Well, when I see "circular motion", one of the first things that comes to mind is *centripetal acceleration*.  For example, Google this:  centripetal acceleration special relativity site:physics.stackexchange.com

Comment: For any accelerating observer in SR, at each instant you may consider a momentarily co-moving inertial reference frame for the accelerating observer, and do Lorentz transformations accordingly. The Lorentz transformation would then be a function of the instantaneous velocity of the accelerating observer.